# SQL SELECT and PHP retrive speed using single table VS join two table?

Tags: php, mysql, join, optimization, database-design

I'm in the process of creating a table then display records. i want to display users height in '**inch**' format  but it will store it in '**cm**' forma in users table.
Now I want to know which way will give me faster result ?

Using JOIN

```
// to select records  
 SELECT *.u FROM, h.height_inch user as u join height as h on u.height_cm =h.height_cm 
 WHERE u.user_id = 2 AND ...;
//for display in php  
 foreach($all_records AS $key => $val) {
  echo $val['height_inch'];
  }
```

OR Single User table (Faster/slower than) :

```
 // to select records  
 SELECT * user WHERE u.user_id = 2 AND ...;
//for display in php  
 foreach($all_records AS $key => $val) {
   $height_in_cm = $val['height_inch']
   $height_in_inch= convert_to_inch($height_in_cm); //function for  convert height cm to inch..
    echo $height_in_inch;
  }
```

Comment: You're asking about microoptimization. Why do you think you have a problem at all with performance?

Comment: because i have to display 50 users  records in one page so which way i should go ?

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: So you are asking if is best to create two tables and do a join versus creating one table only and querying that one USER table?

Comment: @ Erick ,yes right .

Comment: Are you really considering using a table to convert from CM to inches, instead of just dividing by 2.54?

Comment: it just a case , means if in another case mathematical operation will not work then which is best solution ?

Comment: The best solution is to keep it simple and not to complicate things because of "what if the asteroid hits the Earth and there's no humanity" type of scenarios. Store the height in centimeters or millimeters, multiply or divide on the db level and display the data in PHP. The less you do, the faster it is.

Comment: i also want to convert Fitch inch to cm (like 5' 8" = 172.7 cm) , is this possible in query level using  mathematical operation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An even faster alternative would be to simply perform the arithmetic in SQL so you don't have to store fixed conversion data or iterate over the results.

```
SELECT height_cm, height_inches as (height_cm / 2.54) FROM table;
```

Comment: it just a case , means if in another case mathematical operation will not work then which is best solution ?

Comment: A join will almost always be faster than doing the work in PHP.

Comment: only one problem now  i want to display both record means height in Fitch inch and cm also like Height : like 5' 8" - 172.7 cm?  i also want to convert Fitch inch to cm (like 5' 8" = 172.7 cm) , is this possible in query level using  mathematical operation ?

Comment: @amitgupta It's possible, but probably too much business logic for a SQL query. I would do it in PHP. If you have others questions, open a new question on SO.

Comment: @ phpisuber01 ok thank for your answer, please mark my question is useful as you answered it. it's working for me.